# TypeError: Cannot read property 'react' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm getting the following error and would like a little help!

```
Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'react' of undefined
```

I wanted to make a code that would add reactions to a certain message, including the guild, channel, and the message id!

Here my Code:

```js
let servidor = bot.guilds.cache.get("guildid");

let canal = servidor.channels.cache.get("channelid");

let mensagem = canal.messages.cache.get("messageid");

mensagem.react("765350841330171904");

mensagem.react("765350842005454858");
```

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=react

Comment: Rap Sherlock, It didn't help me! i want to see where is the error, i know how to add a reaction, but not how to add a reaction in a message with a specific id

Comment: if you understand the documentation, you'll know where its wrong, because all reaction is need send from Message Instance, try `console.log(mensagem)` it will not return Message Instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error means that the message ID is incorrect or, more commonly, that the message is not cached. This might've happened because it was sent before the last time you restarted your bot. Luckily, you can use [`MessageManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch) which will get the message *directly* from Discord's API (or the cache if it's available).

This method does return a promise, so make sure [your function is `async`](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html#how-to-implement-async-await) or you use a `.then()` to handle it.

```js
const servidor = bot.guilds.cache.get("guildid");
const canal = servidor.channels.cache.get("channelid");
const mensagem = await canal.messages.fetch("messageid"); // fetch the message

mensagem.react("765350841330171904");
mensagem.react("765350842005454858");
```